# Which utility allows me to find who is fields of newly found IP ranges

Tags: gratis, linux, networking, network-monitor, network-administration

I have scripts that list newly recognized ip ranges as source or destination.I use to attach the output I'd those script to whois in order to know the orgname of newly linked IP ranges.

Which utility would do this job

PS: An example of script:

```
#!/bin/bash
    ngrep | grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"  |sed '/192.168.*/d'| awk '!seen[$0]++' | while read i
    do
        echo $i | tee -a /root/.config/.gnome-screenshot/.ngrep-whois-org-netrange-$(date-all)
        whois $i | grep -i 'Orgname\|NetRange\|Country' | tee -a /root/.config/.gnome-screenshot/.ngrep-whois-org-netrange-$(date-all)
        echo --------------------------------------------------------------------- | tee a /root/.config/.gnome-screenshot/.ngrep-whois-org-netrange-$(date-all)

    done
```

Comment: What OS? Any price limit? Commercial use required, or personal use only?

Comment: Linux. Situ no Costa at all.

Comment: OK, I've added the corresponding tags. Could you please [edit] your question and include some example(s) on how those IP ranges are listed, and what details you want to include from whois (best describe the entire process, e.g. "script has '123.123.123.123', and I need to find the ORG for it from whois to process both values in this and that way")? A simple batch script might be able to achieve what you need.